# How to organise huge mysql database for emails and search in it

Tags: mysql

I wanted to ask you for your opinion, what would be the ultimate and the best way to store million of emails and search on them, using mysql.

So first the product:
- you have tons of emails, which has to be stored for a very long period
- there is an option to search on subject or content
- you have additional flags ( like tags and other small stuff )

and then you have multiple users, with their own different ( and multiple ) accounts.

So I was wondering what would be best ?
- create database for each and every user, and store his accounts and emails in tables in his own database
- or maybe create some crazy foreign key structured database ( but it will be only 1 database ) not 1000

- or maybe something completely different ?

I would highly appreciate your opinion,
Thanks!

Comment: Once you have persisted the user email data, how do you plan on accessing it?  Using NoSQL might be a viable option for you.

Comment: i am not familiar with NoSQL.  but i will check it, thanks

Comment: Creating a separate DB for each user doesn't sit well with me.

Comment: This may be better directed to the dba forum

Comment: good call   Strawberry i posted it there. Thanks